# Inspect params and return types

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible using Python 3 syntax for declaring input parameters and return value types determine those types? Similarly to determining the number of parameters of a function?

```
def foo(name: str) -> int:
    ....
```

I would like to get `str` and `int` respectively.

Comment: I don't think this is what you're asking but it might be, if you're looking for something like overloading python3 does have [single dispatch functions](https://repl.it/repls/JauntyMellowDownload)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `typing` module has a convenience function for that:

```
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(foo)
{'name': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'int'>}
```

([the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints))

This is different from `foo.__annotations__` in that `get_type_hints` can resolve forward references and other annotations stored in string, for instance

```
>>> def foo(name: 'foo') -> 'int':
...     ...
... 
>>> foo.__annotations__
{'name': 'foo', 'return': 'int'}
>>> typing.get_type_hints(foo)
{'name': <function foo at 0x7f4c9cacb268>, 'return': <class 'int'>}
```

It will be especially useful in Python 4.0, because then [*all* annotations will be stored in string form](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/).

Answer (score 8):

`inspect` can be used:

```
>>> def foo(name: str) -> int:
...     return 0
>>> 
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> sig = inspect.signature(foo)
>>> [p.annotation for p in sig.parameters.values()]
[<class 'str'>]
>>> sig.return_annotation
<class 'int'>
```

@vaultah's method looks even more convenient, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
def foo(name: str) -> int:
    pass

foo.__annotations__
# {'name': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'int'>}

foo.__annotations__['return'].__name__
# 'int'
```

Comment: This still doesn't guarantee `name` is going to be `str`. You can pass an `int` there and it will work

Comment: @AndrewChe I don't *think* OP is asking about enforcing type hints, although I agree that the wording is hard to understand.